# How to discern a grammatical function of this phrase? Where to place commas?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, supplementation

> “We've got to live, **no matter how many skies have fallen**.”
>   ― D.H. Lawrence, *Lady Chatterley's Lover*

What may you discern a grammatical function of this phrase *no matter how many skies have fallen.*?

I thought a comma mostly goes after dependent phrases, or maybe mostly clauses(?), maybe like

> ***No matter how many skies have fallen***, we've got to live.

May you get to write it like that?

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of the governed exhaustive conditional, which involves a type of clausal adjunct. :)

Comment: I thank you, F.E.. So may this seem like a conditional phrase? I may not get clausal adjunct. I may not get why there seems a comma. I guess I thought commas go mostly after dependent clauses. I may somewhat get adjuncts from this.

Comment: But for the type your example uses, the conditional part (adjunct) is considered to be always true. So, your first example has the meaning of: *“We've got to live."* The adjunct part ("no matter how many skies have fallen") merely gives some extra info. Usually there is no comma in examples like your first one; but a writer could put one in there if they wanted to.

Comment: So maybe that comma seems maybe mostly a maybe writer selection. And I guess *no matter how many skies have fallen* seems an adjunct not *We’ve got to live.*? I thank you, F.E.. I think I liked that information.

Answer (score 2):

The comma's purpose often is to mark a "clause boundary". Consider the following sentences (which mean pretty much the same thing) although in the first, the main clause is at the end, and in the second, the main clause is at the front:

**Any way you slice it, it's baloney.

It's baloney, no matter how you slice it.**

NOTE: *Baloney* aka bologna is a kind of processed luncheon meat commonly used in American sandwiches; it also has the figurative meaning "nonsense".

So the sentences mean "From whatever angle or point-of-view, it does not make any sense" or "Try as you might to 'spin' the story, people will know that what you are saying is bunkum".

The main clause in each of those sentences is "it's baloney". The other clauses express the condition under which "it" is "baloney":

**any way you slice it...

no matter how you slice it...**

The condition expressed is *exhaustive*.  That is, it addresses every possible circumstance without exception. It is *always* baloney. It is never not baloney.

**No matter how you get to the wedding, get there on time!**

Exhaustive conditional clause:
**No matter how you get to the wedding (by car, train, bus, boat, airplane, hovercraft, helicopter, jet-pack, on foot, on skis, teleporting, *whatever*...)**

Main clause:
**...get there on time!**

[image]

Comment: I think I observed some information on “bunkum”. That seemed interesting. I guess I thought it got maybe dictated commas go after independent clauses. It seems they may go after these (exhaustive)(?) conditional clauses(?) independent I guess or dependent. I guess I think may this seem mostly where a commas may go like that. I guess like *“In a world where there is so much to be done(,)* I felt strongly impressed that there must be something for me to do.” maybe not “I felt strongly impressed that there must be something for me to do(,) *In a world where there is so much to be done.”*

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a semicolon in the sentence like this, "We've got to live; no matter how many skies have fallen." But there are different ways to punctuate it without changing the syntax. One of which is by adding a period after the first independent clause. The other ways to punctuate without changing syntax, that I can think of, have all be discussed above. For regular conversation the way you have changed it seems the most smooth and understandable.   I hope that this helps!